# Oracle IS TABLE OF NUMBER(5) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER Type in Java?

Tags: java, oracle

What is the type of `IS TABLE OF NUMBER(5) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER` in Java? `OracleTypes.ARRAY` gives an `ORA-03115 exception`.

**Update: The whole class:**

```
@Repository
public class MerchantEmvRepository {
    private SimpleJdbcCall updateMerchantEmvTerminalData;

    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public MerchantEmvRepository (DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource (){
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        this.updateMerchantEmvTerminalData
                = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("RetCodeType", OracleTypes.ARRAY))
                .withCatalogName("data")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .withFunctionName("update_merch_emv");
    }

    public Array updateMerchantEmvTerminalData (String merchantId) {
        SqlParameterSource incomingParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("i_merch_id", merchantId);
        return updateMerchantEmvTerminalData.executeFunction(Array.class, incomingParameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code which provide this error please?

Comment: @YCF_L updated the initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such type. Using oracle associative array from java is very limit. There are 4 methods in `OraclePreparedStatement/OracleCallableStatement` classes which allow  for this. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraint.htm#JJDBC28179.

Documentation is for oracle 12 but it also should work in oracle 9+

Comment: Could you include the methods in your answer. Link can die, future people finding your answer could not get the same content... See [answer] about links